# How to count number of items in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

It is better explained in example.

I have the following data in MySQL

```
   Name   address   age    
   John1   33 St    20    
   John2   22 St    21
   John3   44 St    20
   John4   55 St    21
   John6   44 St    20
   John5   66 St    35
```

I would like to get list of rows with counts based on age. But is it possible to get the last row associate with each count. Example

```
   Name   address   age   Count 
   John6   44 St    20      3
   John4   55 St    21      2
   John5   66 St    35      1
```

Comment: It's clear that you want the counts of the ages. You'll have to explain why you included the Name, address and age of the rows that you did. Why John6 instead of John3 or John1 for age 20? Perhaps update your question with this information.

Comment: Because the last row is the latest and it keeps changing.

Comment: How one should determine which row is last or latest? There's a rule that rows in a table don't have any specific order. You should choose a criterion to order by. And please, *update your question too* with that information (use the *Edit* link).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the syntax for [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT *, count(*) as Count FROM tableName GROUP BY age;
```

#### UPDATE

Let's assume you decide to add an ordering column, like a datetime:

```
   Name   address   age created   
   John1   33 St    20  2011-04-01 10:00:00
   John2   22 St    21  2011-04-01 09:00:03
   John3   44 St    20  2011-04-01 07:00:20
   John4   55 St    21  2011-04-01 08:45:01
   John6   44 St    20  2011-04-01 13:00:00
   John5   66 St    35  2011-04-01 12:00:40
```

Then you could accomplish your final goal like so:

```
  SELECT *, count(*) as Count
    FROM ( SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY created DESC ) as newTable
GROUP BY age;
```

You must use a nested select because otherwise `ORDER BY` would be applied *after* `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Does that return the last row from the table?

Comment: It should return one record for each age, with an age count.

Comment: Trying to select the last-inserted-row-per-age is relying on your data to be inserted in a specific order, which is not a very good idea.  You will need to add a new incremented field, or an ordering field, if you want to return a specific row in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephen pointed out, you need to do a nested select, but the other way around:

```
SELECT 
    u.Name,u.Address, u.age, u.NumCount
FROM (SELECT Name, Address, age, count(age) from users group by age) as u
ORDER BY u.NumCount desc
```

Comment: I don't think your nested `group by` will necessarily return the last inserted row for each particular age group.  The problem is that the OP wants the `order by` to happen first.  Also, a derived table must have an alias.